# How to generate the desired oscillation graph? [MATLAB]

Tags: matlab

I have a mathematical equation that describes a dynamical system as
[image]

The parameters are defined as follows

```
k1=1; S=1; Kd=1; p=2; tau=10; k2=1; ET=1; Km=1;
```

I coded the system as

```
y(1) = 1; % based on the y-axes starting point in the last figure
y(2) = y(1) + k1*S*Kd^p/(Kd^p + y(1)^p) - k2*ET*y(1)/(Km + y(1)); % to avoid errors

for t=1:100
     y(t+1) = y(t+1) + (k1*S*Kd^p/(Kd^p + y(t)^p) - k2*ET*y(t+1)/(Km + y(t+1)));
end
plot(y);
```

*Note that I did not use tau=10 for simplicity and instead used a delayed version by 1 instead of 10 (because I am not sure how to insert a delay of 10)*

And obtained the following result
[image]

However, I need to obtain this
[image]

Can anyone help me rectify the mistake in my code?

Thanking you in advance.

Comment: For starters `y(t+1) = y(t+1) + ...` should really be `y(t+1) = y(t) + ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we assume that for `Y(t) = 0 for t < 0` then you're code could be modified to produce a similar plot. However, it looks like the plot you are looking to generate uses different initial conditions. If you're just looking to measure `Tc` then it appears that the signal stabilizes with the period you're looking for.

```
k1=1; S=1; Kd=1; p=2; tau=10; k2=1; ET=1; Km=1;

% time step size (tau MUST be divisible by dt to ensure proper array indexing)
dt = 0.01;

% time series
t = -10:dt:100;

% initialize y to all zeros so that y(t)=0 for all t<0 (initial condition)
y = zeros(size(t));

% Find starting and ending indexes to iterate from t=0 to t=100-dt
idx0 = find(t == 0);
idx1 = numel(t)-1;

% initial condition y(0) = 1
y(idx0) = 1;
for n = idx0:idx1
    % The indexing used here ensures the following equivalences.
    % y(n+1) = y(t+dt)
    % y(n) = y(t)
    % y(n - round(tau/dt)) = y(t-tau)
    %
    % Note that (y(t+dt)-y(t))/dt is approximately y'(t) 
    % Solving for y(t+dt) we get the following formula
    y(n+1) = y(n) + dt*((k1*S*Kd^p/(Kd^p + y(n - round(tau/dt))^p) - k2*ET*y(n)/(Km + y(n))));
end

% plot y(t) for t > 0
plot(t(t>0),y(t>0));
```

Result

[image: Result Plot]

Seeing as things stabilize we can take the values in one of the periods and use those for the initial conditions and we get.

[image]

Edit: To elaborate, the function contains a delay of 10 which means that instead of just a single initial condition at y(0), we also need to initialize all values from t=-10 to 0. In the code posted in this answer I arbitrarily assumed that y(t) = 0 for t < 0 and y(0) = 1 because I don't know otherwise. Once we run the code and see that the signal becomes periodic we can *borrow* the values from one of these periods to use those as the initial conditions.

From the diagram you posted we can use our intuition to guess that, before time 0, the signal probably looks something like the region highlighted in the figure below.

[image]

If, rather than using zero to initialize y at y < 0, we copy the values in the red highlighted region, then we get a plot that is more like what you desire.

To get the plot shown above I ran the script once, then found the indices in `y` for the part I wanted to use as initial conditions, then copied those into a new array.

```
init_cond = y(7004:8004);
```

Then I changed script to use this array as the initial condition and changed the initial y values to

```
y = zeros(size(t));
y(1:1001) = init_cond;
```

and ran the modified script again.

Edit 2: The built-in function [`dde23`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dde23.html) appears to be applicable for your problem. To see an example run the command `edit ddex1` in the command window.

Comment: Sorry but I could not understand this part   
`Seeing as things stabilize we can take the values in one of the periods and use those for the initial conditions and we get.`  

Could you elaborate more on this?

Comment: Thank you so much for the help.